# Adding animation to QPushbutton enterEvent and exitEvent

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to add custom animation to QPushbutton without making a custom QPushbutton and overriding its enterEvent() and leaveEvent().

So far I've tried this,

```
@staticmethod
def addButtonHoverAnimation(button:QPushButton,currentPos:QPoint):
    '''
    Method to:
    => Add hover animation for provided button
    '''
    enterShift = QPropertyAnimation(button,b'pos',button)
    exitShift = QPropertyAnimation(button,b'pos',button)

    def enterEvent(e):
        pos=button.pos()            
        enterShift.setStartValue(pos)
        enterShift.setEndValue(QPoint(pos.x()+3,pos.y()+3))
        enterShift.setDuration(100)
        enterShift.start()
        Effects.dropShadow(button,1,2)
        

    def leaveEvent(e):
        pos=button.pos()            
        exitShift.setStartValue(pos)
        exitShift.setEndValue(QPoint(pos.x()-3,pos.y()-3))
        exitShift.setDuration(100)
        exitShift.start()
        Effects.dropShadow(button)
    

    button.enterEvent=enterEvent
    button.leaveEvent=leaveEvent
```

But when I move the mouse very quickly in and out of the button before the animation finishes, The button starts to move wierdly towards the North-West direction.

Button Animation Using Dynamic Positions

[image]

I figured out this was due to the leaveEvent() being triggered before enterEvent() even finishes and also because the start and end values are dynamic. So, I tried providing *currentPos* as a static position and using it instead,

```
@staticmethod
def addButtonHoverAnimation(button:QPushButton,currentPos:QPoint):
    '''
    Method to:
    => Add hover animation for provided button
    '''
    enterShift = QPropertyAnimation(button,b'pos',button)
    enterShift.setStartValue(currentPos)
    enterShift.setEndValue(QPoint(currentPos.x()+3,currentPos.y()+3))
    enterShift.setDuration(100) 
    exitShift = QPropertyAnimation(button,b'pos',button)
    exitShift.setStartValue(QPoint(currentPos.x()-3,currentPos.y()-3))
    exitShift.setEndValue(currentPos)
    exitShift.setDuration(100)  


    def enterEvent(e):  
        button.setProperty(b'pos',exitShift.endValue())
        enterShift.start()
        Effects.dropShadow(button,1,2)
        

    def leaveEvent(e):
        exitShift.start()
        Effects.dropShadow(button)
    

    button.enterEvent=enterEvent
    button.leaveEvent=leaveEvent
```

On running, as soon as the mouse enters the QPushbutton, it moves to the top-left of its parent widget and the animation starts working fine. I can't figure out why this is happening. But I was able to get that, it only happened when I used any static value in the animation.

Button Animation with Static Position:

[image: Button Animation with Static Position]

Here is an example:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QPoint, QObject, QPropertyAnimation
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
# This is the same method mentioned above
from styling import addButtonHoverAnimation


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout=QVBoxLayout()

        button1 = QPushButton("Proceed1", self)
        layout.addWidget(button1)

        button2 = QPushButton("Proceed2", self)
        layout.addWidget(button2)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.resize(640, 480)
        addButtonHoverAnimation(button1)
        addButtonHoverAnimation(button2)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = Widget()
    view.show()

    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I added the MRE as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that probably when the state is changed from enter to leave (or vice versa) the previous animation still does not end so the position of the widget is not the initial or final position, so when starting the new animation there is a deviation that accumulates. One possible solution is to initialize the position and keep it as a reference.

On the other hand you should not do `x.fooMethod = foo_callable` since many can fail, in this case it is better to use an eventfilter.

```py
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QPoint, QObject, QPropertyAnimation
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget


@dataclass
class AnimationManager(QObject):
    widget: QWidget
    delta: QPoint = QPoint(3, 3)
    duration: int = 100

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__init__(self.widget)
        self._start_value = QPoint()
        self._end_value = QPoint()
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)
        self.animation.setTargetObject(self.widget)
        self.animation.setPropertyName(b"pos")
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self._start_value = self.widget.pos()
        self._end_value = self._start_value + self.delta
        self.animation.setDuration(self.duration)

    @cached_property
    def animation(self):
        return QPropertyAnimation(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.widget:
            if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
                self.start_enter_animation()
            elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
                self.start_leave_animation()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def start_enter_animation(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.setStartValue(self.widget.pos())
        self.animation.setEndValue(self._end_value)
        self.animation.start()

    def start_leave_animation(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.setStartValue(self.widget.pos())
        self.animation.setEndValue(self._start_value)
        self.animation.start()


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        button1 = QPushButton("Proceed1", self)
        button1.move(100, 100)

        button2 = QPushButton("Proceed2", self)
        button2.move(200, 200)

        self.resize(640, 480)

        animation_manager1 = AnimationManager(widget=button1)
        animation_manager2 = AnimationManager(widget=button2)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = Widget()
    view.show()

    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

184 / 5000
Resultados de traducción
If you are using a layout then you must reset the position since the layout does not apply the position change immediately but only when the parent widget applies the changes.

```py
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        button1 = QPushButton("Proceed1")
        button2 = QPushButton("Proceed2")

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button1)
        lay.addWidget(button2)

        self.resize(640, 480)

        self.animation_manager1 = AnimationManager(widget=button1)
        self.animation_manager2 = AnimationManager(widget=button2)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.animation_manager1.reset()
        self.animation_manager2.reset()
```

Comment: I totally get your code and what you have done. I like the approach and thanks for the tip. It is working fine if I run this code. But if I use this same code in my application then the 2nd problem occurs, for some reason.The one with the button going to the top-left edge of the parent.

Comment: @SatyamNiranjan I cannot analyze code that I have not seen so I have required an MRE, I have not asked you to place a piece of code. So if you want more help then you must provide an MRE.

Comment: Does a button, being in a layout anyhow, has an effect on this? Because it seems like the button is moving out of the layout and is sticking to the default location in the parent.

Comment: @SatyamNiranjan It does have an effect. My code does not assume this, so I ask you to provide an MRE. I don't want to implement code based on your layout conjecture and after you point out that it doesn't work either and then I ask you again (almost begging you) for the MRE and you just provide it, let's save time please.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have added the UI file as well as the basic code for the dialog.

Comment: @SatyamNiranjan I want an MRE, not just pieces of code so please find out what I mean by reading the link in addition to passing the [tour]

Comment: pls check the update, I have added the example at the last.

Comment: that works flawlessly. But does this mean that I'd have to override the resizeEvent() everywhere I use this, throughout my application?

Comment: I tried adding self.reset() before the self.start_enter_animation() in the event filter and resizeEvent() was not needed anymore. It works perfectly.Thank you for your time.